# Eleventy (11ty) Data Pagination - Title from data

Tags: pagination, nunjucks, yaml-front-matter, eleventy

Trying to setup pagination with data, where `{{ title }}` in `<head><title>{{ title }}</title></head>` is the title of the **current** page as defined in *projects.json*

Assumed this could be done:

```
# main.njk

<head>
 <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
```

```
# page.njk
---
layout: main.njk
pagination:
    data: projects
    size: 1
    alias: project
permalink: "work/{{ project.title | slug }}/"
title: {{ project.title }}
```

Might have misunderstood some fundamentals but `{{ title }}` renders out as `[object, object]` instead. Permalink works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project title can actually be accessed with `{{ project.title }}` in the master template `main.njk`, as with any other project data defined for that project in `projects.json`.

For any other page (not defined as an object in `projects.json`), a conditional statement can be used:

`<title>{{ project.title if project.title else title}}</title>`

So that:

```
# main.njk

<head>
 <title>{{ project.title if project.title else title}}</title>
</head>
```

```
# page.njk
---
layout: main.njk
pagination:
    data: projects
    size: 1
    alias: project
permalink: "work/{{ project.title | slug }}/"
---
```

```
# other_page.njk
---
layout: main.njk
title: Other Page
---
```

```
# projects.json
[
    {
        "title": "Project 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Project 2"
    }
]
```

Outputs:

```
# work/project-1/
<head>
 <title>Project 1</title>
</head>
```

```
# work/project-2/
<head>
 <title>Project 2</title>
</head>
```

```
# other-page/
<head>
 <title>Other Page</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 10):

Now `eleventyComputed` can be used

```
# main.njk
<head>
 <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
```

```
# page.njk
---
layout: main.njk
pagination:
    data: projects
    size: 1
    alias: project
permalink: "work/{{ project.title | slug }}/"
eleventyComputed:
    title: "{{ project.title }}"
```

Comment: `renderData` instead of `eleventyComputed` worked for me but this appears to be a deprecated feature according to this: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/advanced-order/. Time to upgrade.